# recuperar arquivo txt em formatado com utf-8 em python

Tags: python-3.x, txt, utf-8

Estou com dificuldades em recuperar arquivos .txt com python para popular listas ou dicionários, o problema é que esses arquivos não vem com a formatação em uft-8.
exemplo de conteúdo txt:
qual é a data de hoje? (aqui vem um tab separando)   askdate

código python que faz a leitura do arquivo:

```
lines = open("cmds.txt", "r").readlines()

#adicionando os comandos no dicionário
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')#removendo os espaços
    parts = line.split("\t") #separação por tab
    dict_cmds.update({parts[0] : parts[1]})
```

esse for popula um dicionário e se eu printar o dicionário em seguida ele não reconhecerá o "é".

Comment: No `open()` você já pode definir o tipo de codificação, na [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data) explica isso melhor.

Answer (score -1):

É simples, apenas um parâmetro a mais:

```
    file = open('cmds.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    for f in file:
        print(f)
```